# How to install one GUI program on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, package-management

I am using Ubuntu Server 10.10 in a VirtualBox. I need to install a single GUI program (RubyMine) on it.

I checked out installing `ubuntu-desktop` with `apt-get`, and it wants me to install 430 new packages (including OpenOffice). I installed the server in the first place to keep the install as clean as possible!

How do I do a minimal install of (all packages *needed*) to run that single GUI program?

I created a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and added the following:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
```

But `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` still says:

```
0 upgraded, 430 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 155MB of archives.
After this operation, 542MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install X without a complete desktop environment but to be upfront and honest, installing `ubuntu-desktop` is probably the quickest and config-free method of doing what you want.

For our media centre, I use a simple stack of: `nodm` → `xserver-xorg` → `openbox`. It's *very* raw but it allows me (with a bit of scripting) to have the system boot to X and then launch the media centre application (Boxee here). I could probably have gone without `openbox` but it's nice to have some sort of Window Manager just in case I do want to run something else.

When I was doing it, I followed a whole raft of different documentation but the bulk of it is [summed up here](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=417853742697). In short you should be aiming to:

1. Install `nodm`, X, etc.
2. Configure `nodm` by telling it what user to run as (I do suggest creating a non-root user)
3. Create a `~/.xsession` file to boot whatever application you want to be running. In my case this is:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   exec /home/oli/uberboxee
   ```

   You'd just swap out `/home/oli/uberboxee` for your launcher.

Just as a side note, if you install something that requires, for example, GTK, you'll find it might pull in a *massive* number of recommended packages. To keep things light, I strongly consider you run your `apt-get install`s with the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

The [Low Memory System page on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) is a good resource for finding alternatives to the Gnome desktop. Installing a desktop suite is going to bring a lot of stuff but it might save you a little bit of configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your insights..I am infact looking at the ubuntu help for low memory systems; also i did try `--no-install-recommends` but it doesn't seem to work (says no such option). I'm looking into using Damn Small Linux now.

Comment: Sorry, I can't access facebook: http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=417853742697 :( Could you add add different link to this information? thx

Comment: Also, found this link on how to configure `nodm`: http://staff.blog.ui.ac.id/jp/2010/07/06/creating-your-own-booth-in-gnulinux-ubuntu-lucid-nodm/

Comment: ok, after a few hours of struggling I figured out I didn't have `xinit` installed (I'm using ubuntu server.) `sudo apt-get install xinit` solved that problem. Reboot and now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install a clean desktop environment, try Gnome or KDE for starters this will give you a graphical interface without the extra software each distribution is coming with.

Comment: How do I install a *clean desktop environment* on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: @Zabba sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment

Comment: You can always get the code and build it yourself there is an analytic guide in gnome.org