# Are there any small GUI packages for Ubuntu?

Tags: server, package-management, desktop-environments

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 Server, but I need a GUI and ability to run programs like web browser. It doesn't have to be pretty.
I have checked `gnome` and `kdefull` - those require like 1300 and 1450 MB. Quite too much (and I have a slow connection, so it will take a while). There's also `gnome-core` - 800 MB. Is it usable, is it even a desktop? Are there any other minimalistic desktop packages (Gnome, KDE or whatever)?

P. S. I don't care about size to download too much, what I *really* care about is RAM consumption.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install one GUI program on Ubuntu Server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37735/how-to-install-one-gui-program-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Check the question above, the request there is very similar to what you need, it might fit, if not you can always drop a comment on the other question.

Comment: You can try `fluxbox` (about 15Mb to download)

Comment: @BrunoPereira: How is it a duplicate? I know _how_ to install, I'm asking recommendations on _what_ to install!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Well the title is not but all the content of the other question is the same as you have: other user wants to install RubyMine you want a web-browser, other user uses server, you use server, both want to install as minimum packages as possible in they system to be able to run a GUI program. Even the answer is similar! Cmon, no? No similarities? Nothing at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bare minimal [LXDE](http://lxde.org). It uses `openbox` as window-manager but panel, menus,file-managers are all-set

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lxde-core`

Comment: Thanks! That's the one Mint is using? I like Mint's appearance :)

Answer (score 5):

[Openbox](http://openbox.org/) by itself with tint2 isn't bad for light systems and virtual machines. See Ubuntu community wiki page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox) for installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Install `xorg` and some minimal window manager like `twm`. If you think twm is a bit too minimalistic or ugly have a look at http://xwinman.org/ - most of the window managers there are available under Ubuntu.