# Installation of graphical desktop changes kernel?

Tags: server, kernel, gui

I've a Ubuntu Server 11.10 amd64 installation that needed a graphical desktop to execute some visual apps.

While searching for the correct way to achieve this, I noticed that there are a lot of people saying that invoking the gnome desktop installation (apt-get install ubuntu-desktop) would switch from server to desktop kernel. Is this true!? I've checked and the kernel seems to remain unchanged after the install.

I need to be sure of this because the desktop flavoured kernel doesn't seem to support the ServeRaid 8K controller sitting on my IBM server and I have no idea on how to enable support for it. (I'll be grateful if someone could point me a good guide on how to install ubuntu when the storage controller is not detected)

Any comment on this matter will be greatly appreciated!

Good linuxing!

Comment: Well the dependencies of `ubuntu-desktop` doesnot list linux-image-server as conflict as well as trying to install linux-image-server didnot try to remove linux-image in my case.So I guess its untrue. Basically `ubuntu-desktop` is a meta package that installs many default applications. I recommend you to install only required gui applications as well as DE. E.g. `unity` http://askubuntu.com/questions/84147/are-there-any-small-gui-packages-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

We would not expect the kernel to be changed by installing ubuntu-desktop.  The default kernel is typically selected based on the installation media, so if you used an ubuntu-server CD image you would expect to have the server kernel installed.