# Disable desktop environemnts and customize startx

Tags: unity, command-line, xorg

Is it possible to install ubuntu12.04 normally and then disable the desktop environments somehow, so that `startx` doesn't bring up unity or gdm or anything like that?  I'm aware of ubuntu alternative and ubuntu minimal, but I'm asking if I can get `startx` to bring up just a window manager or whatever I tell it to in `.xinitrc` after having installed ubuntu with unity.

If possible I would like to leave unity or something installed so that I can bring it up if I want/need to, but not have it/gdm come up by default

Comment: That's what the Minimal CD is for.

Comment: I'd personally opt for server over minimal. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/1807/how-can-i-strip-down-ubuntu/1808#1808

Comment: Also see this answer for some explanation on how I use NoDM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37735/how-to-install-one-gui-program-on-ubuntu-server/37748#37748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu wiki has instructions for creating a custom [X session](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession).  And then I found a couple of how tos for creating custom Desktop Environments, [One on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1929623) and [one on Make Tech Easier](http://www.maketecheasier.com/easily-create-a-custom-lightweight-desktop-environment/2010/08/10).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to remove unity:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common
```